# Where to find ancient mathematics in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, mathematics

I am a professional mathematician and an avid Latinist, and I would like to be able to read and write mathematics in Latin.
I prefer classical style, so I would like to read some ancient mathematical texts in Latin.
Writing modern mathematics does require some adjustments, of course, but I would like to have some classical style examples.

Can someone suggest some ancient mathematical texts?
I was unsuccessful at finding any.
If there are many options, I would prefer something that is considered good style (like Caesar or Cicero in prose).
Ancient translations from Greek or any other language to Latin are fine.
I assume at least some parts of Euclid's [Elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_Elements) were translated in antiquity, but I could not find Latin translations made before 16th century.
The text need not be an entire book on mathematics, as long as there is a part dedicated to it.

Comment: Boethius translated many Greek texts (mathematical and otherwise) into Latin, but I can't track down any of them.

Comment: The question "where to find modern mathematics in Latin" also has an interesting answer:  Riemann's prize submission to the Paris Academy, from 1861!

Comment: @MattF., that looks interesting as well. That is actually not far from what I work on as a mathematician, so I will certainly take a look. (For anyone curious: The Latin text can be found [here](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Paris/) in various formats.)

Answer (score 11):

The French national library has been scanning a lot of material throughout the years, available on their website [Gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr). Using their advanced search tool we can narrow down to works in Latin about mathematics: [here is a direct link to that query result](http://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&startRecord=0&maximumRecords=50&page=1&exactSearch=false&query=%28dc.language%20all%20%22lat%22%29%20and%20%28dewey%20all%20%225%22%29&filter=sdewey%20all%20%2251%22).

Similarly on [archive.org](http://archive.org), by finding the collection on mathematics and narrowing down to those written in Latin one can find the [following material](https://archive.org/details/texts?and[]=subject%3A%22Mathematics%22&sort=-downloads&and[]=languageSorter%3A%22Latin%22).

In both cases however it should be noted that all material is from 1400 to 1900, I didn't see anything older than this unfortunately, so no ancient mathematicians there. Euler, Descartes, Huygens etc. however all wrote in Latin, so one can find their work at both those links. A couple of ancient Greek mathematicians are translated in Latin there, but the translations are all from the 18th/19th century.

**Edit:** I also found [this website](http://www.wilbourhall.org/) that contains a lot of ancient mathematicians' works, some of them translated in Latin, but, again, those translations (as far as I can see) are all post-15th century.

Comment: Thanks! Those look like useful resources. This does not really answer my question about ancient sources, but I appreciate the answer anyway.

Comment: And even if they do not have at this point any ancient sources, they might one day, when and if such a source (if it exists) is scanned.

Comment: I think the question was about "ancient" sources, not mediaeval or early modern ones. Anyway, the corpus of ancient Latin literature is very well known and thoroughly researched and catalogued. Scanning a few more copies is not going to reveal any unknown works.

Answer (score 9):

Boetius's *Arithmetica* is one example, from around 500 AD.  See the [manuscript](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasures-boethiuss-arithmetic), the [text](https://archive.org/details/aniciimanliitor01friegoog), or a [summary](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27957920). The book provided a Latin version of Nichomachus’s *Arithmetica* (which was in Greek from around 100 AD), which in turn covered some of the number-theoretic topics in Euclid’s *Elements* (from around 300 BC). All three books discussed the sieve of Eratosthenes, the Euclidean algorithm, and perfect numbers.

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you. I will try to find the time to look deeper into this.